# What is the legal significance of explicitly designating an ingredient as a fruit oil?

Tags: food, south-africa, food-processing

A South African food item lists an ingredient as olive (fruit) oil.

Another South African food item lists an ingredient as non-hydrogenated palm (fruit) oil.

I’ve never seen such designations on ingredient listings and assume that it has some legal significance to specify that it is a fruit oil (as in an oil of the olive fruit, rather than the seed) in South African law.

Comment: Most likely for customs duty purposes. But idk.

Answer (score 2):

This may be historical with a quasi-legal underpinning. Apparently, regulations that might have banned palm kernel oil were repealed, but they would not have banned palm fruit oil. It is most likely there to inform consumers that these are the fruit oils, and not palm kernel or olive seed oil (the latter would not be generally used in food, the former is almost universally what people outside Africa mean when they speak of "palm oil"). Palm kernel oil is regulated in the US in a way that palm fruit oil is not, and I can't find any evidence that olive seed oil is legal in food, in the US.

Comment: Would you think that the palm kernel oil was banned for/by environmental or health related reasons/legislation?

Comment: If it was (banned, alternatively subject to greater strictures), I would assume it was health-related with environmentalism a lesser likelihood, since the repealed regulations were in terms of the content of the lipids and not their circumstances of birth.

Comment: Could you perhaps give any more specific references to such as the  repealed regulations To which you refer?